# Xamarin ViewCell containg another ListView?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble getting my model to show up when trying to databind it in XAML setting Xamarin's BindingContext...here's my simplified model code:

```
public class LeagueRootObject
{
    public League League { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
    public object Error { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlayingDate { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public MatchDetail MatchDetail { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class MatchDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public PlayerDetail PlayerDetail { get; set; }
    public object Rating { get; set; }
    public int MatchPlayerId { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and here's simplified XAML snippet:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Matches}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="{Binding Path=MatchDetail.Name}"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Players}">
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextCell Text="{Binding Path=PlayerDetail.FirstName}"/>
                  <!-- another ViewCell here seems to hide data somehow -->
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

which is placed in the root `StackLayout` element of the Xamarin `ContentPage` and whose `BindingContext` is set to the `LeagueRootObject` instance loaded properly from json (which I've checked in debugger as working).

The XAML code above is the best I've been able to do since adding `Label` inside the `StackLayout` contained in the inner `ListView`'s `ViewCell` just doesn't show up properly...how can you add a `ViewCell` (or any other type of cell for that matter) to the inner `ListView` and build its `View` so it can show all the data belonging to all of the inner collection objects (I'm currently only getting the first one to show up also which is a problem when there's more than one player)...what am I doing wrong, should a `ListView` not be used that way and have some other 'View` control be used for outer objects, all I want is to show all inner objects grouped inside outer ones somehow please...

Thanks

Comment: Seems my json model code and deserialization wasn't working properly, I've used json2csharp to create it and then tweaked it, leaving me with properly loaded matches (assuming it was working right) and nothing in their details...I'm about to recreate it and see if it works...will say if the databinding code works then.

Comment: I managed to properly load the inner object now (since I tweaked the names I forgot to add JsonProperty attributes) and it could show some elements now using `GroupHeaderTemplate` but the inner `ItemTemplate` don't still show up, so the question stands...what is wrong with the XAML code above?

Comment: With a ListView you don't use the BindingContext but ItemsSource

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't see how using BindingConext of the ListView-containing ContentPage instead of directly setting it's ItemSource is a really bad thing..given outer Collection shows I think it's fine..is it not?

Comment: To be honest never saw nobody trying to set the bindingcontext of the listview, and every documentation on Xamarin site and examples only use the ItemsSource

Comment: I just noticed that in my code above ListView's DataTemplate had no ViewCell and their corresponding Views defined at all...but when I add it to both ListViews it still only shows the first one...so the question may be is it possible to create a ViewCell containing another ListView in it or should another Cell type be used and how please?

Comment: ViewCell is the base cell type, in theory you can use anything inside it, maybe it's a bug on the Forms framework.

Comment: Thank you for your interest&help, hoping Microsoft adds Xamarin.Froms support to Blend soon, because I'm really bad at this...exchanging the second inner ViewCell with a TextCell seems to show the inner text, but only the first one in the inner collection, so I'm definitely doing this wrong...but the idea of how to do databinding is at least similar if not the same to WPF (in contrast to what I first thought). p.s. I'll update the above question XAML to the one showing data both from collections

Comment: LOL, that's just a dream for now, oh god, i would pay a thousand dollars for it (yes, the business edition :D)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to me maybe being bad at Xamarin-flavoured XAML you also maybe right about there being bugs in the way the listviews work...since I just tried the above code on Windows 10 mobile and there it would not show any data of the inner collection but running it on Android worked by showing multiple inner collection last names...and after scrolling down past that outer collection object it would crash the app.

So, this may not be the way to show such a list of inner objects (and something like a button action beside each of them) grouped by belonging to outer collection onjects, but I still can't find another one example in XAML.

Could it be that you can only do that in foreach looped code in Xamarin.Forms 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your issue, I could suggest you solution that helped me to show ListView in ListView.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598179/5912513

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for some reason that doesn't work on the model above, at least it's not showing up at all properly on windows platforms and partially on android, I think it's a bug of XF2.0 and I ended up doing it in code with two nested foreach loops. Thanks all the same though.